# Not enough parameters for sql statement. Want to update table (python-mysql connect)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

import sys
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='anohacker', database='csproj')
cursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)

nameb=input("enter your name: ")
bookbor=int(input("Enter book code to borrow: "))

def borrow(nameb,bookbor):

```
bquery="update inventory set name_of_borrower=%s where book_code=%s"
stock1="update inventory set in_stock=in_stock-1 where book_code=%s"
stock2="update inventory set borrowed=borrowed+1 where book_code=%s"
cursor.execute(stock1,bookbor)
cursor.execute(stock2,bookbor)
cursor.execute(bquery,nameb,bookbor)
mydb.commit()
```

borrow([nameb],[bookbor])

I want to take name and book code from user and update my mysql table columns with them. But it's giving me an error. Most answers are for insert into but I want to update table.

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide the data for the query as a tuple so:

```
bquery="update inventory set name_of_borrower=%s where book_code=%s"
cursor.execute(bquery,(nameb,bookbor))
```

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But it's still not working. When I remove one of the variables it works but it doesn't with 2 variables.